# Using multiple CKeditor instances in same page in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ckeditor

I am new to Angular and I am trying to fix a bug in the system which was created many years ago.

We have following structure in the UI.
[image]

And the card items are created dynamically using a loop.

```
<ol class="session-list list-group">
    <session-card ng-repeat="session in EventService.event.sessions|orderBy:'getStartDate()'" session="session" ng-class="{selected:session==EventService.currentSession}"></session-card>
</ol>
```

And HTML for the `session-card` is in SessionCard.html file. And it contains basic HTML code for a `<li>`. When you click on the Session Card (Card Item) it should load the right hand side with the correct session data.

This works perfectly when you use HTML form elements such as `input`, `textareas`.

But this description is displayed using a CKeditor instance.

```
<ckeditor name="description" ng-model="session.description"
                          ></ckeditor>
```

The problem with this one is, when I have multiple Card Items as shown in the image, the description I enter goes in both Card Item's CK editors automatically. I need to be able to enter different descriptions for both card items.

Can someone point me in the right direction how to fix this. Thank You.

Comment: name="description{Index}" Try this

Comment: Tried that and tried name="description-{{session.id}}, but it does not make a difference

Comment: can you share your code via like stackblitz,sandbox etc..?